# android:layout_width="wrap_content" does not work in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486458/1112407) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4353846/1112407) assert that an `android:layout_alignParent*` property creates a circular reference between a RelativeLayout and a child view. However, given a simple layout *without* any `android:layout_alignParent*` properties:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="test text blah blah"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: relativelayout sucks]

The layout width of the RelativeLayout turns out to be `match_parent`, not `wrap_content` as specified in the XML above.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `layout_width` of ListView items are automatically changed to `match_parent`. The layout above works outside of a ListView.